# Combining Multiple Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a few projects with individual scripts for different tabs of a single spread sheet. They are used to sort data from a form submission.

```
var sheetToSort = "Expenses";
var columnToSortBy = 1;
var rangeToSort = "A2:I";

function sortExpenses() {
  var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetToSort);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeToSort);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
}
```

and then i have another one;

```
var sheetToSort = "Investments";  
var columnToSortBy = 1;
var rangeToSort = "A2:E";

function sortInvestments() {
  var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetToSort);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeToSort);
 range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
}
```

If i try to add this script in the same project as the first script, it will only work on one tab, not both.

What is the correct way of doing this without having multiple projects?

Comment: The reason these won't work together is you are using the same variables (`sheetToSort, columnToSortBy, rangeToSort, sheet, range`) for two different functions.  Rename one set of the variables and fix the associated function, and it should work together.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment you can just rename the variables and it will work fine.

BUT

The whole logic of having modular code is to enforce reusability. That means to refactor the common code which are being used at several places into a separate module/function and then re-use that same where ever needed.

Your sort function is same logic-wise for both expenses and investment; only the sheet name, column, range changes differs. So you can refactor the code to sort a sheet by taking these as arguments into another function and perform sorting there. This way you'll be able to reuse the code with sorting functionality, only attributes will change based on arguments passed.

You can do something like this :

```
function sortExpenses() {
  // One way to call
  var sheetToSort = "Expenses";
  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var rangeToSort = "A2:I";
  sortSheet(sheetToSort, rangeToSort, columnToSortBy)
}

function sortInvestments() {
  // If you're not re-using those variable you can directly pass the values like this
  sortSheet("Investments", "A2:E",1);
}


function sortSheet(sheetToSort, rangeToSort, columnToSortBy) {
  var sheet =
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetToSort);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeToSort);
  range.sort({
    column: columnToSortBy,
    ascending: false
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Thanks @Umair.  This modularity is still new to me.  Your example will definitely help me as well!

Comment: @RonKloberdanz Great to know you found it helpful. :-)